# how to auto hide jquery reveal plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using [jQuery reveal plugin](http://foundation.zurb.com/old-docs/f3/reveal.php). How to set auto hide e.g. in 5 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just need a simple [timer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Timers) for this. This is the line of code you need to solve the issue:

```
setTimeout(function(){ $('#myModal').trigger('reveal:close'); }, 5000)
```

And here's full code to open the modal and have it auto-close 5 seconds after being opened:

```
$('.button').on('click', function(){
  $('#myModal').reveal()
  setTimeout(function(){ $('#myModal').trigger('reveal:close'); }, 5000)
});
```

As a finishing touch, here's the functionality abstracted more cleanly into a function:

```
$('.button').on('click', function(){
  $('#myModal').reveal();
  delayedHideModal('#myModal', 5)
});

function delayedHideModal(selector, sec){
  setTimeout(function(){ $(selector).trigger('reveal:close'); }, sec*1000)
}
```

Comment: Most welcome! If this did work, make sure to mark the answer as accepted so other people know : )