# Hide a popup plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the Reveal jQuery plugin. http://www.zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin

How to set auto hide e.g. in 5 seconds?

I found this code more it does not work and I do not know in which file to include it : [how to auto hide jquery reveal plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18348506/how-to-auto-hide-jquery-reveal-plugin/18348559)

```html
/*
 * jQuery Reveal Plugin 1.0
 * www.ZURB.com
 * Copyright 2010, ZURB
 * Free to use under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
*/


(function($) {

/*---------------------------
 Defaults for Reveal
----------------------------*/
  
/*---------------------------
 Listener for data-reveal-id attributes
----------------------------*/

 // $('a[data-reveal-id]').live('click', function(e) {
 //  e.preventDefault();
 //  var modalLocation = $(this).attr('data-reveal-id');
 //  $('#'+modalLocation).reveal($(this).data());
 // });

 $(document).on('click', 'a[data-reveal-id]', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var modalLocation = $(this).attr('data-reveal-id');
  $('#'+modalLocation).reveal($(this).data());
 });

/*---------------------------
 Extend and Execute
----------------------------*/

    $.fn.reveal = function(options) {
        
        
        var defaults = {  
      animation: 'fadeAndPop', //fade, fadeAndPop, none
      animationspeed: 300, //how fast animtions are
      closeonbackgroundclick: true, //if you click background will modal close?
      dismissmodalclass: 'close-reveal-modal' //the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
     }; 
     
        //Extend dem' options
        var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options); 
 
        return this.each(function() {
        
/*---------------------------
 Global Variables
----------------------------*/
         var modal = $(this),
          topMeasure  = parseInt(modal.css('top')),
    topOffset = modal.height() + topMeasure,
            locked = false,
    modalBG = $('.reveal-modal-bg');

/*---------------------------
 Create Modal BG
----------------------------*/
   if(modalBG.length == 0) {
    modalBG = $('<div class="reveal-modal-bg" />').insertAfter(modal);
   }      
     
/*---------------------------
 Open & Close Animations
----------------------------*/
   //Entrance Animations
   modal.bind('reveal:open', function () {
     modalBG.unbind('click.modalEvent');
    $('.' + options.dismissmodalclass).unbind('click.modalEvent');
    if(!locked) {
     lockModal();
     if(options.animation == "fadeAndPop") {
      modal.css({'top': $(document).scrollTop()-topOffset, 'opacity' : 0, 'visibility' : 'visible'});
      modalBG.fadeIn(options.animationspeed/2);
      modal.delay(options.animationspeed/2).animate({
       "top": $(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure + 'px',
       "opacity" : 1
      }, options.animationspeed,unlockModal());     
     }
     if(options.animation == "fade") {
      modal.css({'opacity' : 0, 'visibility' : 'visible', 'top': $(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure});
      modalBG.fadeIn(options.animationspeed/2);
      modal.delay(options.animationspeed/2).animate({
       "opacity" : 1
      }, options.animationspeed,unlockModal());     
     } 
     if(options.animation == "none") {
      modal.css({'visibility' : 'visible', 'top':$(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure});
      modalBG.css({"display":"block"}); 
      unlockModal()    
     }
    }
    modal.unbind('reveal:open');
   });  

   //Closing Animation
   modal.bind('reveal:close', function () {
     if(!locked) {
     lockModal();
     if(options.animation == "fadeAndPop") {
      modalBG.delay(options.animationspeed).fadeOut(options.animationspeed);
      modal.animate({
       "top":  $(document).scrollTop()-topOffset + 'px',
       "opacity" : 0
      }, options.animationspeed/2, function() {
       modal.css({'top':topMeasure, 'opacity' : 1, 'visibility' : 'hidden'});
       unlockModal();
      });     
     }   
     if(options.animation == "fade") {
      modalBG.delay(options.animationspeed).fadeOut(options.animationspeed);
      modal.animate({
       "opacity" : 0
      }, options.animationspeed, function() {
       modal.css({'opacity' : 1, 'visibility' : 'hidden', 'top' : topMeasure});
       unlockModal();
      });     
     }   
     if(options.animation == "none") {
      modal.css({'visibility' : 'hidden', 'top' : topMeasure});
      modalBG.css({'display' : 'none'}); 
     }  
    }
    modal.unbind('reveal:close');
   });     
    
/*---------------------------
 Open and add Closing Listeners
----------------------------*/
         //Open Modal Immediately
     modal.trigger('reveal:open')
   
   //Close Modal Listeners
   var closeButton = $('.' + options.dismissmodalclass).bind('click.modalEvent', function () {
     modal.trigger('reveal:close')
   });
   
   if(options.closeonbackgroundclick) {
    modalBG.css({"cursor":"pointer"})
    modalBG.bind('click.modalEvent', function () {
      modal.trigger('reveal:close')
    });
   }
   //$('body').keyup(function(e) {
          //if(e.which===27){ modal.trigger('reveal:close'); } // 27 is the keycode for the Escape key
   //});
   
   
/*---------------------------
 Animations Locks
----------------------------*/
   function unlockModal() { 
    locked = false;
   }
   function lockModal() {
    locked = true;
   } 
   
        });//each call
    }//orbit plugin call
})(jQuery);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can add the below code from the answer [how to auto hide jquery reveal plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18348506/how-to-auto-hide-jquery-reveal-plugin/18348559)

```
$('.button').on('click', function(){
  $('#myModal').reveal();
  delayedHideModal('#myModal', 5)
});

function delayedHideModal(selector, sec){
  setTimeout(function(){ $(selector).trigger('reveal:close'); }, sec*1000)
}
```

Add this code in the js file where you are calling the Reveal plugin. you can use any other selector than `button` class also on click of which you are opening the Reveal plugin.  The example uses `setTimeout` which triggers the `reveal:close` event handler.Here `#myModal` is the selector which you want to open in Reveal plugin.

Usage : Create a HTML file (e.g test.html) or any other HTML file where you want to include  the javascript files like below

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- Add jquery file as dependency of reveal.js-->
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Add reveal plugin -->
<script src="jquery.reveal.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

function delayedHideModal(selector, sec){
  setTimeout(function(){ $(selector).trigger('reveal:close'); }, sec*1000)
}

$('.button').on('click', function(){
  $('#myModal').reveal();
  delayedHideModal('#myModal', 5);
});

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myModal">
this is inside reveal
</div> <br/> <br>
<button class="button">Click here to reveal</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. This is in the file jquery.reveal.js? I tried to paste the code but no, it does not work

Comment: No this should be an external js file which is using the jquery.reveal.js file . I will update my code.

Comment: Sorry I'm lost I did not understand :(

Comment: You need to add  the javascript code to your HTML page where you are using the reveal plugin. you cannot write in within the library you have to use another javascript file which calls the reveal() method of the plugin.

Comment: You javascript code add a button to my page. I want the popup to close automatically after 5 seconds, your code does not work

Comment: Are you seeing the popup in your page after clicking the button?

Comment: I can not click the button because the popup is above

Comment: Can you post the code of your page where you are going to use this Reveal.js plugin?

Comment: you have pm ? it's possible?

Comment: I am not sure if pm allowed in stackoverflow

Comment: How can I contact you?

Comment: Here is my codementor profile https://www.codementor.io/niladrisekhardutta you can post your problem there, I can help